# Cocos2d searching for images in removed directory

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I'm working with Spritebuilder to build a simple app. I was using a Smart Sprite Sheet, but a while ago I noticed I kept receiving random errors that would come and go, and they were always related to the sprite sheet. I wasn't sure what was wrong with it, so I just removed the sprite sheet and transferred everything out of the sprite sheet into the main directory of the app. Then, I reassigned all sprite objects to match the new directory. Everything works and looks fine, but upon running the app I receive warnings in the log that cocos2d is missing a file. As I mentioned previously, everything looks fine when the app is actually run.

This is the exact warning I receive:

```
2014-07-05 16:33:35.087 Test App[6972:60b] cocos2d: Couldn't find file:AppAssets/Shopping Cart.png
```

AppAssets is the Smart Sprite Sheet that I deleted. This error is received for every sprite that is being used in the app. The sprite appears as it should when run, the only difference is the location of the file.

I am creating all the sprites in SpriteBuilders interface, not programmatically.

Comment: Do the images exist in the app bundle?

Comment: open your .ccb files in text editor or use spotlight to find if this file is still referenced somewhere in your project (or code)

Comment: @trojanfoe yes and no, like I said previously I just moved the images out of the sprite sheet AppAssets and relocated them right outside the sprite sheet folder. There is no directory called AppAssets (which was the name of the sprite sheet) anymore, but the images exist in the app bundle and are used without any issues. All I had to do is edit the image location of each sprite in SpriteBuilder. The only problem is that it is still trying to find AppAssets, which is deleted.

Comment: @trojanfoe Found the issue! I completely overlooked the selections for highlighted icons, which were set to Assets/whatever.png.